# Install coreutils in microsoft hosted azure devops agents

Tags: azure-devops

Is there a way to install coreutils in Microsoft hosted azure devops ubuntu-16.04 or 18.04 agents.

Basically we need to run md5sum command as part of our build process.

Apt-Get Install -y coreutils gives the following error: apt-get: command not found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are on hosted agent, unlike you used to do on Linux. Please give a try with below command

```
 sudo apt-get -y install coreutils
```

Password-less `sudo` is documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#capabilities-and-limitations).

> Run as an administrator on Windows and a passwordless sudo user on
>   Linux

If above way is still not working, suggest you use [self-hosted agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-linux?view=azure-devops) as a workaround.